# React Child error from one function is referencing another function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is now all of my code:

```js
import styles from './Add.module.scss';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import {IonPage, IonGrid, IonCol, IonRow, IonCardSubtitle, IonCard} from '@ionic/react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';


const CategoryPage = () => {
  const {category} = useParams();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [loading2, setLoading2] = useState(true);
  const [categoryinfo, setCategoryinfo] = useState('');
  const [categoryname, setCategoryname] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const showjokes = ({category}) => {
      try {
        fetch(`https://fakeurl.herokuapp.com/categorypage/${category}/`, {
          method: 'GET',
          mode: 'cors',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        })
          .then(res => res.json())

          .then(data => {
            console.log('chisora', JSON.parse(data.jokes));
            setLoading2(false);
            const categoryjokes = JSON.parse(data.jokes);
            console.log('categoryjokes', categoryjokes);
            setCategoryinfo(categoryjokes);
            console.log(JSON.parse(data.jokes), '<==== here is data');
            getcatname({category});
          });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('update, error time!', error);
        return false;
      }
    };
    showjokes({category});

    const getcatname = ({category}) => {
      try {
        fetch(`https://fakeurl.herokuapp.com/getcatname/${category}/`, {
          method: 'GET',
          mode: 'cors',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        })
          .then(res2 => res2.json())

          .then(data2 => {
            console.log('parker', JSON.parse(data2.categoryname));
            const categorynombre = JSON.parse(data2.categoryname);
            console.log('categorynombre', categorynombre.category);
            setCategoryname(categorynombre.category);
            setLoading(false);
            //console.log(JSON.parse(data.categoryname), "<==== here is data")
          });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('update, error time!', error);
        return false;
      }
    };
  }, []);

  console.log('checking loading', loading, loading2);
  //console.log("the stuff",categoryinfo[0].joke_category)
  const stuff = categoryinfo;
  console.log('stuff', stuff);
  console.log('categoryname', categoryname);
  if (loading2 || loading) return <p>loading</p>;

  return (
    <IonPage>
      <h1>{categoryname} jokes</h1>
      <IonGrid className={styles.bottomContainer}>
        <IonRow>
          <IonCol size="12" className="ion-padding-start">
            <IonCardSubtitle className={styles.heading}>
              {categoryname} jokes
            </IonCardSubtitle>
          </IonCol>
        </IonRow>
        <div className={ styles.recentNotes }>

            { stuff.map((note, index) => {

                return (
                                

            <IonRow key={ `note_${ index }` } className="animate__animated animate__faster" id={ `noteRow_${ note.id }` }>
                <IonCol size="12">
                        <Link to={`/Update/${note.id}`}>
                                            <h2>{note}</h2>
                        </Link>
                </IonCol>
            </IonRow>
                            );
                        })}
        </div>

      </IonGrid>
    </IonPage>
  );
};

export default CategoryPage;
```

As you can see there are two functions in the `useEffect`: one to get an array of joke data and the other to get the name of the category the joke is in.

This is my error message:

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {joke, joke_name, joke_owner, joke_category, id}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

And it points to `setLoading(false)` within the `getcatname` function.  The object that is referred to in the error is referring to the object that I get from the `showjokes` function.

The console.logs right before I check the two loading hooks log the data just perfectly.  In other words, the functions in the `useEffect` do their job as far as the end product is concerned.

There is a lot I don't understand here.  What is the "React child" that is being referred to?  When I look around for solutions it seems to come up in render functions, but my error is simply pointing to the `setLoading` hook part.  Why am I getting an error that seems to be referencing what is going on in another function but the error is within the other function?

Edit:
Straight from postman:

data =

```
{
    "jokes": "[{\"joke_name\": \"scar lengthening\", \"joke_owner\": 1, \"id\": 5, \"joke_category\": 5, \"joke\": \"eventually scar tissue lengthens when they get tired of being pulled\"}, {\"joke_name\": \"bummer\", \"joke_owner\": 1, \"id\": 45, \"joke_category\": 5, \"joke\": \"Scar Tissue is a bummer\"}]"
}
```

data2 =

```
{
    "categoryname": "{\"category_owner\": 1, \"id\": 5, \"category\": \"scar tissue\"}"
}
```

Comment: I formatted your code (using [Prettier](https://prettier.io/)) to make it easier for others to read. I had to add a few closing tags to your return JSX for the parser to accept it. Please review the last edit (#3) to make sure it's correct.

Comment: @jsejcksn looks good to me.  I really need to work on making my code look more normal!  Thanks!

Comment: So React is complaining as you are trying to render an Object (it doesnt know how to do this). It looks like the Objet it is trying render is the state `categoryinfo`.

You turn `categoryinfo` into `stuff` when you do
`const stuff = categoryinfo`
Neither of these variables apear in the return. It seems like some code is ommitted?

Comment: @JackMcKayFletcher  Updated with all of the code now!  I liked the object because I thought I could take out specific parts of the object.  But I'm a beginner, so I probably am misunderstanding.  I thought I've done it before.

Comment: @filifunk try using ``JSON.stringify`` where you think your error is occurring.

Comment: It appears that `note` is not a string, but an `object`. Can you also include in your question an example of what `data` and `data2` look like?

Comment: Can you give the correct url or at least an example of your object?

Comment: Try using ``JSON.stringify(note)`` to better understand the problem

Comment: could you also show contents of `stuff`?

Comment: @jsejcksn  I updated in the post a copy and paste of what I get from postman for `data` and `data2`.  Sorry if it isn't really readable, I realize I could have manually taken out the backslashes.

Comment: @JackMcKayFletcher  Stuff = https://imgur.com/a/wQs7ayW

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So because `note` is an object, you can not use it as a string, unless you transform it with `JSON.stringify(note)` to understand the problem. But actually, if you just want the `joke` inside the `object`, you can use `note.joke` to access it.

Like this:

```
  {stuff.map((note, index) => {
        return (
            <IonRow key={`note_${ index }`} className="animate__animated animate__faster" id={ `noteRow_${ note.id }` }>
                <IonCol size="12">
                    <Link to={`/Update/${note.id}`}>
                         <h2>{note.joke}</h2>
                    </Link>
                </IonCol>
            </IonRow>
         );
  })}
```

Comment: worked!  any particular reason why `setLoading` seemed to be pointed to in all of my errors?  No matter where I put it.  It would point to it.

Comment: @filifunk happy to hear that! Sorry, I do not the reason for that last question. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Ah I see the bug now :). You have a bug in the map function:

```
stuff.map((note, index)....
```

index here is not the index of the list as you expect - rather it is another element of the list stuff. This is an object which you are rendering in full. This is why you are seeing the error about rendering an object.

your map function should just take 1 arguement. You can then get index of that element as such:

```
stuff.map((note) => {
   const index = stuff.indexOf(note)

})
```

Answer (score 0):

In this part of your component's JSX:

```js
stuff.map((note, index) => {
  //...
})
```

you have nested within the `<Link>` an `<h2>`:

```jsx
<h2>{note}</h2>
```

This is the source of the problem. `note` here is one of the objects from the array in `data.jokes` from your API response.

You'll need to convert this into a `string` before using it as the content inside the `<h2>`. If you want just the joke, you can use

```js
<h2>{note.joke}</h2>
```

or you can use the name of the joke:

```js
<h2>{note.joke_name}</h2>
```

etc.

Answer (score -1):

I hope you imported IonPage, IonGrid, IonRow, IonCol, IonCard

Comment: I did import those yes